# How can I get require once to work in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I moved my site from local host to live and the "require once" seems to have broken.

> require_once(): Failed opening required 'wp-content/themes/my-theme/layout/twitterAPI.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/share/pear')

I have tried:

`require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/demo/wp-content/themes/my-theme/layout/twitterAPI.php';`

`require_once(get_template_directory().'/layout/twitterAPI.php');`

`include( get_template_directory() . '/layout/twitterAPI.php' );`

`require_once('twitterAPI.php');`

Comment: did you upload site in demo folder?

Comment: have you ensured that file exists?

Comment: Yes the file is there in the correct folder.

Comment: Try `require_once __DIR__ . '/relative-path-from-this-file/layout/twitterAPI.php';` and see if that helps. I doubt that `require_once` is broken though since WP uses that internally... a lot. It would throw errors way before it comes to your code.

Comment: Are you using child theme? You may use get_stylesheet_directory() function for child theme directory path.

Answer (score 0):

Using this worked:

`require_once __DIR__ . '/twitterAPI.php';`

I am using a child theme and the file is in the same folder I am requiring it from.

Still unsure the reason as my previous method worked on local host, but not live.